I want to build a functional mech that is open-sourced and crowdfunded. How do I do this?
It's been a dream of mine to own a mech for as long as I could remember. I know this seems silly to most of you, but to me, I can't think of anything cooler. Building a mech is expensive and my previous attempts at getting rich failed so funding my fantasy build is currently impossible. I have attempted to opensource some of my projects, but I can't seem to attract anyone to pay attention.
Just for context this is my first attempt at open sourcing, and I have the updated code with added functionality on my github:
[Mod. comment: the author removed two links here (as is his/her right) but they can be seen in the edit history (as is also right and proper) if future readers find they are helpful to add context to the question.]
Anyways, what am I doing wrong? what should I do to have a successful crowdfund for my opensource projects? Is this the right board to ask this question?

Is your question about building a community that supports your project idea (financially and with know-how)? Try this search. Maybe a good start is to try out a less derogatory nick that is not scaring people off ;-)

@Martin_in_AUT At least from an English point of view, I see the poster's username as self-deprecating, implying they are the stupid one, not the reader. However, you make a fair point that implication may not be what a worldwide population sees.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@PhilipKendall I perfectly understand that the poster's username is self-deprecating, but in both cases (serious or funny) it would not motivate me to participate.

@MisterMoron, it's not acceptable to vandalise your own question, however poor it is, once it's received answers; that invalidates those answers and wastes the time other people put into them.  This question's now closed, but please leave it as is.


It's been a dream of mine to own a mech for as long as I could remember.

And it's fine to have dreams - but you also need to be able to make a realistic assessment of what's possible given your current skills, current technology, etc. Building a mech is a multi-billion dollar project (probably actually trillions); anyone investing that sort of money is going to expect a significant return on their money.
That means starting with a business plan, not with code. Your business plan can include "open source everything" if that's what you want.
